# How to install a locale en_IN?

Tags: command-line

On my CentOS 6 server I have

```
locale -a | grep en_IN
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
```

But on my macOS Mojave I don't have it. Is there a way to install en_IN locale on macOS 10.14.6 ?